# Take + FetchMany + returning unexpected results

Tags: nhibernate

I am trying to figure out how to do a Take and FetchMany Together.

```
var c = session.Query<Table1>().Take(5).FetchMany(x => x.Table2).ToList();
```

I expect this to return 5 rows from Table1 and unbound result from Table2. Instead I get one row back from Table1 and 5 rows from Table2.

```
var c = session.Query<Table1>().Take(1000).FetchMany(x => x.Table2).ToList();
```

I get 309 records from Table1(it has 6200 total records).

I don't get how nhibernate decided to return that many records.

Comment: you seem to be running into a lot of issues with Nhibernate.. :D

Comment: Yes. I am....does not help too that I am more use to writing stuff in linq but have to write it in HQL. So trying to get it work in linq then moving on to HQL

Comment: moving from Linq to HQL is not smthing anyone would recommend.. you are introduce a  tight coupling between your model and repo code..

Comment: Nono. I have a project that is like nhibernate 2.0 that uses hql. Right it seems to be decided it has to stay at nhibernate 2.0 with hql. However that project takes a while to run so I have my own mockups to test things out before I implement into the main project. Sometimes it seems easier for me to first right in linq then try to convert it to hql.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

well I am not sire but how this has a bearing on your code, but fetchmany will bring the whole result set to memory and then Take the specified subset.

use joinqueryover or joinalias to achieve the same..

```
var c = session.Query<Table1>().Take(5).FetchMany(x => x.Table2).ToList();
```

this becomes

```
Table2 table2Alias=null;
var c = session.QueryOver<Table1>().JoinAlias(x => x.Table2,()=>table2Alias).Take(5).ToList();
```

let me know if it works out for you.. or you can write an HQL query instead

Comment: The end goal is to have HQL. With your QueryOver example one. I tried something similar that I found on stack (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5704311/bound-fetchmany-in-linq-to-nhibernate). I am wondering though how yours works vs that one.

Comment: Also I noticed with your QueryOver it does return 5 records but as far as I can tell they are all the same. They have the same Id and same information.

Comment: I also wanted to ask. Does take always take a subset from memory when using a fetch?

Comment: So is it possible to do what I want to do? Or is this a limitation of nhibernate (doing a take that is not in memory)

Comment: regarding your question about returning 5 records always.. is it the case that you just have 1 record in Table1??

Comment: No it has 6200 records in Table1. I filtered by distinct and it returns just one row(so the other 4 where the same record).